# Dropbox Python API not updating file

Tags: python, api, raspberry-pi, dropbox

my code is uploading a txt file to my drop box, but the document it self is empty of content. It only reading inside the title of the file 'test_data.txt', the data itself which is in the real file is not there. The file never updates either when running the script a second time, but I suspect this is because the file is not being updated (it's not actually reading the contents of the .txt file). If anyone could help me with this I would appreciate it.

```
import dropbox
from dropbox.files import WriteMode
overwrite = WriteMode('overwrite', None)

token = 'xxxx'

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(token)
dbx.users_get_current_account()
dbx.files_upload('test_data.txt', '/test_data.txt', mode = WriteMode('overwrite'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files_upload` should recieve a content to upload. In your current code you are asking to upload string "`test_data.txt`" as file "`/test_data.txt`".

```
with open('test_data.txt', 'rb') as fh:
    dbx.files_upload(fh.read(), '/test_data.txt')
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for loading the actual data onto Dropbox. I seem to be having a problem with the over write though I think once I try to run it again? Do you know why that is? Here's the error:



39790e91b2e957d2ab8414f990', UploadError(u'path', UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError(u'conflict', WriteConflictError(u'file', None)), upload_session_id=u'AAAAAAAAE-y8ZxAODG-lkg')))

Comment: use `mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite` param in `files_upload`